# Apollo Server, typescript, and graphql-modules: graphql_1.parse is not a function

Tags: typescript, graphql, graphql-js, apollo-server

This started happening seemingly randomly, no idea what's causing it. There's no stacktrace or any hint of why it's happening or where it's coming from.

I've tried googling around but the only results I can find is from a bug in apollo over a year ago that's already been fixed.

(SO is telling me to add more non-code stuff, but I don't really have much else to say lol. The error is literally just `graphql_1.parse is not a function`, doesn't give me much to go off of.)

The relevant stuff:

```js
// index.ts

createConnection().then(() => {
  console.log(' Database connected');

  const server = new ApolloServer({
    typeDefs: graphQLRoot.typeDefs,
    resolvers: graphQLRoot.resolvers,

    formatError: (err) => {
      if (err.extensions.code === 'BAD_USER_INPUT') {
        return {
          code: err.extensions.code,
          message: err.message,
          invalidData: err.extensions.exception.invalidData,
        };
      }

      return new Error('Internal server error');
    },
  });

  server.listen(3000).then(({ url }) => {
    console.log(` Server ready at ${url}`);
  });
}).catch(error => console.error(error));
```

```js
// graphql/shelf.ts

interface IGetShelfInput {
  id: number;
}

interface ICreateShelfInput {
  shelf: Shelf;
}

interface IAddToShelfInput {
  id: number;
  scriptId: number;
}

export default new GraphQLModule({
  typeDefs: gql`
    input ShelfInput {
      id: ID
      title: String!
      scripts: [Script]!
    }

    type Shelf {
      id: ID
      title: String!
      scripts: [Script]!
    }

    type Query {
      listShelves: [Shelf]
      getShelf(id: Int): Shelf
    }

    type Mutation {
      createShelf(shelf: ShelfInput): Shelf
      addToShelf(id: Int, scriptId: Int): Shelf
    }
  `,

  resolvers: {
    Query: {
      async listShelves(): Promise<Shelf[]> {
        return Shelf.find();
      },

      async getShelf(_: any, args: IGetShelfInput): Promise<Shelf> {
        return Shelf.findOne(args.id);
      },
    },

    Mutation: {
      async createShelf(_: any, args: ICreateShelfInput): Promise<Shelf> {
        const shelf: Shelf = new Shelf();
        shelf.title = args.shelf.title;

        const validationErrors = await validate(shelf);

        if (validationErrors.length > 0) {
          throw new UserInputError('Invalid data', {
            invalidData: validationErrors,
          });
        } else {
          return shelf.save();
        }
      },

      async addToShelf(_: any, args: IAddToShelfInput): Promise<Shelf> {
        const shelf = await Shelf.findOne(args.id, { relations: ['scripts'] });
        const script = await Script.findOne(args.scriptId);

        shelf.scripts.push(script);

        return shelf.save();
      },
    },
  },

  imports: [Scripts],
});
```

```js
// graphql/index.ts

export default new GraphQLModule({
  imports: [Scripts, Shelves],
});
```

```
// package.json

"dependencies": {
  "@graphql-modules/core": "^0.7.7",
  "apollo-server": "^2.7.0",
  "graphql": "^14.4.2",
},
```

**Edit:** For what it's worth, I don't get this issue if I compile the whole thing then run it with `node dist/index.js`